# How do I determine scrollHeight?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I determine scrollHeight of a division use css overflow:auto?

I've tried:

```
$('test').scrollHeight();
$('test').height(); but that just returns the size of the div not all the content
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a chat and always have the scroll bar to the current message on the screen.

So I was thinking something like the following:

```
var test = $('test').height();
$('test').scrollTop(test);
```

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: What is wrong with using scrollHeight() ?

Comment: @BadrHari: There is no `scrollHeight()` function in jQuery.

Comment: it's $('test').get(0).scrollHeight();

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`scrollHeight` is a regular javascript property so you don't need jQuery.

```
var test = document.getElementById("foo").scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me: var height = document.getElementById("chatLog").scrollHeight - $('#chatLog').height();
  $('#chatLog').scrollTop(height);

Comment: What about browser support? All major versions of browsers support it? IE8+?

Comment: @Cupidvogel The linked MDN page says IE8+

Comment: To get full document height: `document.querySelector("body").scrollHeight;`

Answer (score 370):

Correct ways in jQuery are -

- `$('#test').prop('scrollHeight')` OR
- `$('#test')[0].scrollHeight` OR
- `$('#test').get(0).scrollHeight`

Comment: +1 for $('#test')[0].scrollHeight, given the asker was already using jQuery.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it answers the question.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. Notice that `prop` method requires jquery version 1.6 or larger. +1 from me

Comment: Note this only returns the scrollHeight of the "first" element found and if any elements are currently "hidden" you might get a zero here even if others do have a positive scrollHeight, FWIW :)

Comment: @rogerdpack Good point sir! Although in this example he's using an ID instead of a class as the selector so he should be okay, but nonetheless good point.

Comment: $('#test').prop('scrollHeight') working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: I prefer `$('#test').prop('scrollHeight')`, the other two give a TypeError if the element doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

`$('#test').context.scrollHeight`

Comment: `prop('scrollHeight')` works but `context.scrollHeight` didn't: "Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined"

Comment: Probably best not to go with this method now, it was removed in the 3.0. https://api.jquery.com/context/