# Can't access property once selecting element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can't get the title right. I am using jquery to create a `textarea`.

```
 function build_form() {
      // Clear all previous form elements
      $('#form_content').html('');

      // Grabs all elements that will be dynamically created
      var elements = templates.types[$('#selectType')[0].selectedIndex].content.elements;

      for (ele in elements){
              var $div = $(document.createElement('div'));
              $div.attr('class', 'div_form');

              // Create description for input box
              var $x = $(document.createElement('text'));
              $x.html(elements[ele].description);
              $div.append($x);

              // Create input box itself
              var $i = $(document.createElement(elements[ele].type));
              $i.attr('placeholder', elements[ele].placeholder);
              $i.attr('class', 'form_input');
              if (elements[ele].value) {
                      // For textareas
                      $i.text(elements[ele].value);
                      // For input
                      $i.val(elements[ele].value);
              }

              console.log($x);
              console.log($x[0]);
              console.log($x[0].scrollHeight);
              $div.append($i);

              $('#form_content').append($div);

              var $linebreak = $(document.createElement('br'));
              $('#form_content').append($linebreak);
      }
}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Results of console.log]

This is as much an understanding problem as a problem blocking me. `$x` shows that there is a textarea at `$x[0]` and, expanding it, I see a giant list of properties. One of which is `scrollHeight` which I am trying to access.

However once accessing `$x[0]`, it then gives me the HTML and `$x[0].scrollHeight` results in 0. The text is present.

What am I missing?

Edit: The height of the `textarea` is non-zero. [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375166/1136527

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine scrollHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381817/how-do-i-determine-scrollheight)

Comment: Is the `textarea` visible ? Because if its hidden (*`display:none` on it or a container of it*)  its `scrollHeight` would be 0.

Comment: `textarea` is visible, I didn't screenshot it. @AlexMcMillan I saw that thread. I haven't assigned an ID to this textarea (it is being created dynamically through jquery), so I would just do `$x.scrollHeight` no?

Comment: `$x` is a jQuery object, not a DOM node.  jQuery provides methods for retrieving attributes from the wrapped DOM

Comment: Apologies, `$x[0]` would retrieve the DOM node. Then the equivalent would be `$x[0].scrollHeight`?

Comment: What makes you think `0` is not the correct value?  What are the dimensions of the div according to dev tools element picker?

Comment: According to the element picker, the height of the `textarea` is `28`. The end goal here is to set the height of the `textarea` to the `scrollHeight` so all the text is visible at once. I added proof in my OP.

Comment: *"However once accessing $x[0], it then gives me the HTML and $x[0].scrollHeight results in 0. The text is present.

What am I missing?"* **You are missing the rest of the code that should be in your question not an image**

Comment: @zer00ne Alright, I added the entire function. There is still more code but I can't imagine them playing a part.

Comment: @PejmanPoh These are confusing:`document.createElement('text')` **There's no such thing as `<text>` tag in HTML5** 

`elements[ele].description` **Is that an attribute?**

`document.createElement(elements[ele].type)` **Are you creating a type attribute?**
`templates.types[$('#selectType')[0].selectedIndex].content.elements;` **is this a `<template>` tag, a `<select>`, or ...um a `type` attribute of a `<template>` tag, that is a `<textarea>` / `<select>`???!**

Comment: @zer00ne Ok you got me on `createElement('text')`, that doesn't make any sense. As for `elements`, it is a JSON blob that contains all the attributes for each dynamically created input field/form. I'll add an excerpt of one of these objects to the OP to make it clearer, but there's really not much more code so, if you want, you can see the entire repo https://github.com/PejmanPoh/PejmanPoh.github.io. I'm fairly new to this so apologies in advance for what you may encounter in there. The README should clear things up further. Thanks for your time so far :)

Comment: @PejmanPoh Thanks for the clarification, I think if you want the that distance measured, you should make sure that that particular property is a *frozen* value and if it is it's probably does it's measurement before the textarea is generated. If `$(i)` is your dynamic textarea, then you should definitely place `$x[0].scrollHeight` after it. Or better yet wait for user interaction like input or change event. If you use input event and `scrollHeight in callback, then it could grow as user types.