# jquery: scroll to bottom after AJAX load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a messaging app and I am importing the conversation into the page with AJAX, so I am trying to find a way to have the div scrolled to the very bottom when the page loads. It is important that the div is only scrolled to the bottom on the first load, it should not scroll to the bottom on the refresh timer.

After the contents of `#convo` are **initially** loaded, the div should be scrolled to the bottom. I am trying to use `$("#convo").scrollTop($("#convo")[0].scrollHeight());` but do not get any errors - the solution just simply does not work. Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this task?

```js
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const ID = urlParams.get('DM');
  console.log(ID);

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#convo").load("convo.php?DM=" + ID);
   $("#convo").scrollTop($("#convo")[0].scrollHeight());
      setInterval(function() {
          $("#convo").load("convo.php?DM=" + ID);
      }, 5000);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div id='convo'></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: run the snippet, it shows an error, "scrollHeight is not a function". Check this answer, it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381817/how-do-i-determine-scrollheight/7381859

Comment: @AlexAngelico I have tried this, using both ```$('#convo').scrollTop($('#convo').get(0).scrollHeight);``` and ```$('#convo').scrollTop($('#convo').prop('scrollHeight'));``` but neither work. I do not see errors. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing mistake in this script line:-

```
 $("#convo").scrollTop($("#convo")[0].scrollHeight());
```

1. According to my knowledge, **scrollHeight()** is not any method in JQuery. Even in javascript, the **HTML DOM Property** is **scrollHeight**. There is no paranthesis with this property in Javascript.

Look at the script code mentioned below. Here I use **HTML DOM scrollHeight Property** to get the total height of element. And then give this height as a parameter in **JQuery scrollTop() method**. So the scrollbar directly go to the bottom of the page.

Note:- scrollHeight property give complete height of element even the height that is not viewable (because of overflow).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].scrollHeight;
    $("div").scrollTop(x);
});
```

```css
div{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum quae necessitatibus ab iste, dolore, 
        deserunt iusto similique rerum voluptatum saepe ad consequuntur id commodi non quibusdam architecto
        inventore voluptas. Sunt.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum quae necessitatibus ab iste, dolore, 
        deserunt iusto similique rerum voluptatum saepe ad consequuntur id commodi non quibusdam architecto
        inventore voluptas. Sunt.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum quae necessitatibus ab iste, dolore, 
        deserunt iusto similique rerum voluptatum saepe ad consequuntur id commodi non quibusdam architecto
        inventore voluptas. Sunt.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! This does not appear to be working, probably because of AJAX loading the contents of ```<div id='convo'></div>```. Any advice?

Comment: There is one more trick. just remove parameter inside scrollTop(). And just write 10000 inside scrollTop(). It will go directly to the bottom.  You can increase as many zero's as needed, if your page height is greater 10000.