# strange behaviour of Chrome at window.scrollTo()

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
</head>
```

for reloading the page every 5 seconds.
i'm using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
</script>
```

for scrolling down if necessary.
It works fine with Firefox and Internet Explorer but Chrome scrolls only once when loading the page for the first time. Only when I switch the tab (e.g. Ctrl+t) and go back after 5 seconds (Ctrl+w) Chrome scrolls down to the bottom. This is strange! Do I use window.scroll incorrectly or does Chrome behave incorrectly?
Are there any other possibilities for scrolling to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: While the page is loading, Chrome has a problem with scroll commands. Solution:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)}, 1000);">
```

This works, if loading of page doesn't last more than 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

Comment: What about slow networks? I don't think this would work on every case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `window.scroll()` as an alternative?

```
window.scroll(x, y);
```

Comment: @user2142034 It doesn't? Hmm.. you want scrollBottom right? Check this workaround out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655273/jquery-window-scrolltop-but-no-window-scrollbottom